# 2D Digital Subraction Angiography

Tags: data-request, medical, images

I'm searching the web for an open dataset/database with 2-dimensional medical x-ray images, I can use to perform a DSA for quite a while now. Until now I found a good example on http://www.isi.uu.nl/Gallery/DSA/.

But I can not find any images that are suitable to perform a DSA. Does anybody have a movie during an intervention? The best possible dataset would contain an intervention of a hand or other extremities in 2D. Maybe in a high resolution with a lot of frames? I need to have the mask image and the live image.

I do not need to have any copyright. I just want to play around. And publish (if anybody wants it) the source code. But won't republish the images if there is any restriction.